# Getting group values from Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a Crystal Report which is grouped by a Category.  The categories are from a database, but for sake of argument, the categories are "fixed", and are labeled A-G.  For each group, I have a couple of SUMS for the group and a COUNT of items within the group.  All data displays as it should, and sums and counts are all good.

What I would like to do, since I know the categories (A-G), is to find the fields of each of those SUMs and COUNTs for each category and put them in a table in either the report header or footer, doesn't matter, acting as a summary of the categories, if you will.

So for example, if Category A has a count of 5 and a sum of 100,000, I want to access those two items, find the place in my header/footer where Category A label is, and fill in those values there as well.

How can I do this in Crystal?  I'm thinking I can name the group fields by the category value using the group name formula ("SumOfItemsInA", for example) and put some type of logic in my header/footer to find the SumOfItemsInA field - just don't know exactly how that is done in Crystal.  Any suggestions?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a cross-tab. Using formulas/running totals would make your report a lot less flexible and likely to break.

Comment: The report need not be flexible, the boundaries of the categories are already known and defined.  So I just need an answer to my original question.

Comment: As i said. You can do this with a cross-tab :)